# Hide line items in quote pdf layout

Tags: email-template

In the Quote app I use a force.com app that adds line items to the quote.  When using the standard Salesforce quote template it adds all of the quote line items to the pdf.  Is it possible to use a field and some logic to not display certain line items on the quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quote PDF Template is pretty fixed in what you can change about it, and selectively displaying Quote Products doesn't seem to be available. What I have done before is to use a custom checkbox on QuoteLineItem called "Selected". When this box is checked, the Amount fields are displayed and roll up to the Quote, if it's not Selected, these fields show as blank. Obviously they're still on the quote as sent to the customer, but look more like "notes" than products.

Comment: I'm curious about how you implemented this.  Do you use the Total Price field for the amount?  It seems like there is not a way to manipulate how this field is calculated.  Could you help me understand how this works?

Comment: I created a custom field for the QLI Price/Amount, and custom Rollup Summary field on the Quote that SUMs this field conditionally based on Selected = TRUE and some other logic. If you want to use the standard Total Price fields, you can create a workflow rule on the QuoteLineItem that copies the value from the custom field if Selected is checked, and populates with 0 if unchecked. In my case, it was acceptable to use custom fields from QLI to Quote and from Quote to Opportunity.